# document.fonts.ready is not executing after all fonts loaded. Before fonts loaded it is being executed

Tags: javascript, font-face, font-family

I have below code, which I expected that it will execute after all fonts loaded. But it is not working as expected.

```
document.fonts.ready.then( () => {
    document.fonts.check('14px Poppins'); // returning false always in ready promise
} );
```

But after website completely loaded if check for font existence, I am getting true value

I mean `document.fonts.check('14px Poppins'); // returning true.`

Is that above approach correct, to check whether font is loaded or not?

Comment: Seems like it is **not** working in Chrome's newer version only...